# How do I see the network over a wireless bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a wireless network in our house using an Asus router to connect to the internet and also connected to a second Asus router on the second level to improve the signal strength there. Everything is good.

A few years back I purchased a CPE bridge to provide internet in the barn. I connected it an an older Asus router at that end, and things have been good.

Now I have added some security camera at that end, but I cannot see anything that is connected to the router in the barn. I can't see anything after the master CPE.

What do I need in order to see the connected item at that end?
The network names and passwords are the same on all routers providing uninterrupted WiFi connection between the house and barn.

A picture of the CPE bridge I purchased
[image: picture of the CPE bridge I purchased]

Comment: What matters more is how everything is connected physically and logically.  Please spell it out.

Comment: Please use basic grammatical formatting in questions/answer _(e.g. commas, periods, sentence structure, paragraph structure, etc.)_